# field level permission in django

Tags: python, django, permissions, django-guardian

In django, I can use django-guardian for object level permission for user and groups. But what if I want to set field level permission?

Lets say I have a model as below:

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    reg = models.CharField()
    location = models.CharField()
```

and I have three users in my system and these are **user1**, **user2**, and **user3**

Now I want **user1** will get a permission for all three fields of model **Attribute**. But **user2** will get permission to only ***name*** and **geg** and **user3** will get permission for only the **name** field.

In my system there are a lot of users and groups. Is there any way like django-guardian to set field level permissions in django.

Comment: Are you using django-rest-framework?
If so then there is a tweak for this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Field Level Permission Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398362/field-level-permission-django)

Comment: duplicate as far as a "working solution for the problem" is the solution. I dont know of a reusable app for this problem, as is django-guardian for object level permissions...though.