# Permissions to edit certain fields in Django

Tags: django

I have two different groups who are allowed to access Django-Admin. They are allowed to view all Fields in a Model, but shall not edit all Field. For example G1 is allowed to edit "price" and "ean" whilst G2 is allowed to edit "ean" and "detail".

I tried the version given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398362/field-level-permission-django), but I also want to restrict the editability in the detail view of a model object.

EDIT:
currently, I'm trying to figure out how to access the request user in a ModelAdmin, as I've registered the "special-field-permissions" in the Meta of the model and am trying to modify the readonly_fields depending on the group. any idea how to get the user?

Comment: Consider adding what you've tried so far into the original question. SO works best if you provide more code and ask us to debug. we can't provide code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution i came up with is to overwrite get_changelist and get_form:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    fields = [$$$]  # Default fields for everyone
    if not has_group(request.user, $$$):  # Check if User IS NOT in group
        fields += [$$$]  # Add field that is associated with group to list
    self.readonly_fields = fields
    return super(YourAdminName, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

def get_changelist(self, request, **kwargs):
    fields = [$$$]  # Default fields for everyone
    if has_group(request.user, $$$):  # Check if User IS in group
        fields += [$$$]  # Add field that is associated with group to list
    self.list_editable = fields
    return super(YourAdminName, self).get_changelist(request, **kwargs)
```