# Update only specific fields in a models.Model Django

Tags: django

I have an APP to rate supervisors to personnel in Django.

I have model in `models.py` in my app Django :

```
class SuperviserModel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(db_collation='C')  
    family = models.TextField(db_collation='C')  
    score = models.FloatField(db_column='score ', blank=True, null=True)  # 
    def __str__(self)-> str:
        return f' -  {self.family}  - {self.name}'
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'personnel'
```

And in `admin.py`:

```
@admin.register(SuperviserModel)
class MySuperviserModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name','family','score']
    sortable_by = ['name','family']
    search_fields=['name', 'family']
```

I want when `superviser` user edit personnel just update score field, And cant update name and family field.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify `score` as only [**`.fields`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields):

```
@admin.register(SuperviserModel)
class MySuperviserModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'family', 'score']
    sortable_by = ['name', 'family']
    search_fields = ['name', 'family']
    fields = ['score']
```

Comment: thanks a lotttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `readonly_fields` attribute on your admin model.

From documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields):

> By default the admin shows all fields as editable. Any fields in this option (which should be a list or tuple) will display its data as-is and non-editable;

So you should change your class to:

```py
@admin.register(SuperviserModel)
class MySuperviserModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name','family','score']
    sortable_by = ['name','family']
    search_fields = ['name', 'family'],
    readonly_fields = ['name', 'family']
```

However, if you want more granular control you can check this request:

[Field Level Permission Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20398362/field-level-permission-django)